# How can I keep the container view getting effected by the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a `UITableViewController` inside a Container View that's inside a regular `UIViewController` that has a `UINavigationController`. Because the View Controller is held by a Navigation Controller, the Table View is compensating for the `UINavigationBar`, since it's in a Container View, it shouldn't. How can I keep the TableViewController from compensating for the Navigation Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems the problem wasn't specific to Container Views. I tried the same thing with prototype cells in a regular `UITableView` inside my `UIViewController` that has the `UINavigationController`, and the same thing happened. It appears this is an auto-layout problem or something. So as far as a solution goes, I don't have a real one other than, just make the Container or `UITableView` as large as the `UIViewController` in Storyboards.